# Find out if a specific device is an USB mass storage

Tags: linux, devices, usb-drive, block-device, removable-storage

## Context

I'm automating SD card imaging from an existing `dd` factory image. The SD card is always connected through an external USB card reader and thus appears in the system as a SCSI block device `/dev/sd*`.

Currently the syntax of my command is: `write-image DEVICE` where `DEVICE` is the SD card block device, eg. `/dev/sdd`.

## Problem

I'm already doing a basic check on `DEVICE` to verify it is of the form `/dev/sd*` but this is not enough: I fear the users (production people not used to Linux) make a mistake and specify another seemingly valid device, eg. `/dev/sda`. You can see the looming catastrophe, especially since my imaging script needs root privileges (not to write the image itself, mind you, but to modify the SD card afterwards, including adjusting a partition's size depending on the SD card's real size)...

## Question

I would like to verify that the specified device actually is some USB mass storage (or at the very least a removable device) so that I can protect the system disks from being trashed accidentally. How can I do that?

I found nothing relevant in `/proc` or on the web, I'm quite at loss now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look under the `/sys/` directory. In particular, `/sys/block/` contains symlinks to block devices in `/sys/devices/`.

`/sys/block/sdX/removable` looks like it will read as 1 for a removable device, and 0 otherwise. This gives you a basic check for removability.

I'm not sure if there's a better way to check if it's a USB device, but
`readlink /sys/block/sde` will spit out something like `../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1.2/6-1.2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sde`. Checking if that contains a `usb*` folder might work as a simple check.

You can get other device details like vendor and model from `/sys/block/sdX/device/`, which might also come in handy.