# Removable USB stick listed as non-removable in /sys/block?

Tags: usb-drive, automounting, removable-storage

In my question [Bash script to output path to USB flash memory stick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119243) I got stuck on a problem nobody else seems to be having. (The issue also impedes my desire to use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60335).)

So I made that specific problem into this new question.

Apparently removable devices listed in `/sys/block` end with 1. It is [stated here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80880) and several other places in this site and this principle is used in the answers I referenced above.

My removable device, a Sandisk 64GB flash memory stick, is listed as:

```
/sys/block/sdl/removable:0
```

Apparently, removable devices should end in 1 (and my others do). Why does my USB memory stick not follow the rule?

It was automounted by Dolphin. I'm running Kubuntu 12.04.

Dolphin shows it as "59.6GiB Removable Media".

And it is mounted (automatically) at `/media/me/70E8-1567`

`sudo blkid` shows it as:

```
/dev/sdl1: UUID="70E8-1567" TYPE="vfat".
```

`lsblk -do name,rm` shows:

```
sdl   0
```

And `lsusb -vv` shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
  idProduct          0x5530 Cruzer
  bcdDevice            2.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Comment: How is it listed if you do: lsblk -do name,rm? 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Could you give us `lsusb` ID corresponding?

Comment: @F.Hauri added `lsusb` output. Thanks

Comment: @mikeserv I added output of `lsblk -do name,rm`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, could you please give me the output of: `grep -H . /sys/block/sdl/events` (meaning `sdl` is your usb key;)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### USB removable storage selector: *USBKeyChooser*

Rewrited 2022-01-05:

```bash
USBKEYS=()
while read _{,,,,,,} dev _ rdev;do
    [[ $rdev == */usb[0-9]* ]] &&
    grep -q '^DRIVER=sd$' /sys/block/$dev/device/uevent &&
    (( $(</sys/block/$dev/size) )) &&
    (( $(</sys/block/$dev/removable) )) &&
    USBKEYS+=($dev)
done < <(/bin/ls --color=never -g /sys/block)
```

### Rewind:

In this I

- Ensure this is *USB*
- Ensure device is *removable*
- Ensure this work as an *hard drive* (not a CD-Rom)
- Ensure they have size greater than 0 (not an empty Card reader)

### In fine: *usbKeyChooser*

There is the final version of *usbKeyChooser* subroutine in my [live installer](https://github.com/F-Hauri/debian-live-with-luks/blob/master/live-install):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DIALOG=whiptail

usbKeyChoose() {
    while [ ! -b /dev/$STICK ] ;do
        USBKEYS=()
        while read _{,,,,,,} dev _ rdev;do
            [[ $rdev == */usb[0-9]* ]] &&
            grep -q '^DRIVER=sd$' /sys/block/$dev/device/uevent &&
            (( $(</sys/block/$dev/size) )) &&
            (( $(</sys/block/$dev/removable) )) &&
            USBKEYS+=($dev)
        done < <(/bin/ls --color=never -g /sys/block)

        (( ${#USBKEYS[@]} )) &&
            title="Choose wich USB stick have to be installed" ||
            title="No key found"

        menu=(R "Re scan devices")
        for dev in ${USBKEYS[@]} ;do
            read model </sys/block/$dev/device/model
            menu+=($dev "$model")
        done
        ans=$($DIALOG --menu "$title" 21 72 14 "${menu[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
        if [ ! "$ans" ]; then echo "User aborted."; return 1; fi
        [[ $ans == R ]] || STICK=$ans
    done
} 
usbKeyChoose
[[ $0 == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && [[ $STICK ]] && echo $STICK
true
```

I like this *looping* solution because they

- let insert many keys,
- wait for kernel registration,
- valid the choice,
- default to nothing and
- permit user abort.

Anyway, even if user did wrong `ok` choice, next screen is another choice asking user for which *image* have to be written on key defaulting to *create new image* wich is a very long process where user could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: So you negate ATA devices from your possible results? What if you have an nfs mount? Will your script diskdump on it?

Comment: @mikeserv nfs mount could not be listed by `/sys/block/*/device/`... maybe `dr::bd` (I will look), but not nfs!

Comment: @mikeserv `/sys/block/drbd1/removable` hold `0` and `/sys/block/drbd1/device/vendor` don't exist anyway.

Comment: What about real SCSI? Or serial?

Comment: this works for me. I like it.

Comment: @mikeserv Interesting, but I don't use *real scsi* disk from more than 5 years now... If you have some, maybe could you show me what this *variable* may hold (other than ATA)!?

Comment: Or maybe through `/sys/block/sdl/events`... @MountainX please what's in this (pseudo) file?

Comment: I don't, but if you used lsblk or udevadm you could specify inclusively only those filesystems you would accept, as I noted.

Comment: Or changing for: `sed -ne 's+^.*/usb[0-9].*/\([^/]*\)$+/sys/block/\1/device/uevent+' <(xargs -n1 readlink < <(echo /sys/block/*))`

Comment: @F.Hauri - `/sys/block/sdl/events` is empty

Comment: @MountainX: Ok, the way for ensuring block device is *under* usb go through the use of readlink! (See last edit)

Comment: @F.Hauri - thanks. Works great! I use kdialog, so I posted an answer showing your code working with kdialog here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119895/15010

Comment: @MountainX you could join [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13557/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-mikeserv) if you're intersted to discuss further about my [live-installer](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/live-install.sh.txt).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so to pull this in a list, you can use the [same command I gave you before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119243/bash-script-to-output-path-to-usb-flash-memory-stick/119351#119351), but just drop the **removeable** requirement:

```
% for blk in $(lsblk -ndo name) ; do
>        udevadm info --query=all --name "$/dev/$blk" |\
>        grep -q ID_BUS=usb && printf \
>            'findmnt %s -no TARGET ;'\
>                "/dev/$blk" /dev/"$blk"[0-9]
>        } ; done 2>&- |. /dev/stdin
```

It's no big deal - it will now only output active mountpoints for block devices on the usb bus and I, for one, can't think of many examples of non-removable usb block devices anyway.

Regarding **why** your current device does not register as removeable, the most likely answer is that its driver simply doesn't list it that way. When devices are detected by **`udev`** it pulls in information on them as soon as it can based on its rules database. You can see all of those classifications with:

```
% udevadm info --query=all --name /dev/$BLOCK_DEVICE
```

That will return a list of all of the **key=value** entries the system uses to classify the hardware referenced by **`/dev/$BLOCK_DEVICE`**. At the bottom of [this post slm advises](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119254/52934) how this information can be easily parsed to serve your needs - and it's pretty simple indeed. The documentation rightly describes it as "human-readable, grep-friendly." Above I filter all block devices to only those on the usb bus with:

```
% grep -q ID_BUS=usb
```

You can also `attribute-walk` all the way up the device tree for your current device and another whose `attributes` you think it should reflect. If it doesn't, it is because `udev` assigned it differently than you think it should have. Thankfully, though, you can see every datapoint that affected its assignment with:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/$BLOCK_DEVICE
```

You can use this data to model new assignment rules as you please.

Comment: Unfortunely, this may show empty card reader or empty cdrom.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question: *Why USB stick listed as non-removable*...

Comment: I hope I fixed that just now.

Comment: If you wanna have a look, there is [the whole script](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/live-install.sh.txt):

Comment: I saw it. It's pretty good, but you'd be a lot better off working with the tools as intended instead of manipulating their side effects. The problem with side effects is that they tend to change without notice.

Comment: For most things that's fine, but as I understand it, the intent of this script is to overwrite and entire block device without additional testing. That's pretty severe.

Comment: There is no *intended tools* that do this jobs with LUKS encryption. Live-helper is currently under *strong* development. So *side-effect* that could change without notice could happen, but this have no to be harmfull. Anyway, my script ask for wich device has to be overwritted and let you a chance to stop anything before dangerous operation.

Comment: What could I do as *additional testing* ??

Comment: It asks the user? Then it's perfect. As long as you indemnify yourself by deferring responsibility to the owner of the disk, then whatever you do is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is F. Hauri's answer adapted for kdialog:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIALOG=kdialog

usbKeyChoose() {
    while [ ! -b /dev/$STICK ] ;do
        USBKEYS=($(
                xargs -n1 readlink < <(echo /sys/block/*) |
                sed -ne 's+^.*/usb[0-9].*/\([^/]*\)$+/sys/block/\1/device/uevent+p' |
                xargs grep -H ^DRIVER=sd |
                sed s/device.uevent.*$/size/ |
                xargs grep -Hv ^0$ |
                cut -d / -f 4                 ))
        if [ ${#USBKEYS[@]} -eq 0 ];then
            title="No key found"
        else
            title="Choose wich USB stick have to be installed"
        fi

        menu=(R "Re scan devices")
        i=0
        for dev in ${USBKEYS[@]} ;do
            read model </sys/block/$dev/device/model
            #echo $i $dev "$model"
            menu+=("$i" "$dev $model")
            i=$[i + 1]
        done
        num=$($DIALOG --menu "$title"  "${menu[@]}")
        #echo "num=$num"
        #echo "USBKEYS[num]=${USBKEYS[num]}"
        if [ ! "$num" ] ; then
            echo "User aborted."
            exit 0;
        fi
        [ ! "$num" = "R" ] && [ "${USBKEYS[num]}" ] && STICK=${USBKEYS[num]}
    done; }

usbKeyChoose
echo $STICK
```

Comment: If you've choosed *my* anser for use, why did you not *accept* them?

Comment: @F.Hauri I did choose your answer now. I learned from both answers (yours and @mikeserv) , so thanks to both of you!